# How to modify Unity windows snapping shotcuts

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys

When unity's window snapping is enabled the following short cut's are enabled too:

- snap left : Ctrl+Super+Left
- snap right : Ctrl+Super+Right

Naively I though this was configured in `org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings` in the move-to-side-e/w but it's not.

I'd like to modify these keybindings where can I do that?

Comment: Look's like it's the grid feature of Compiz.
It can be tweaking using CompizConfig Setting Manager...

But then why does disabling of unity windows snapping also disables this ?

Comment: To begin with, you can use <ctrl>+<alt>+[0-9]
<ctrl>+<alt>+4 corresponds to snap left
<ctrl>+<alt>+6 corresponds to snap right

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in CompizConfig Settings Manager (ccsm) under Window Management -> Grid -> Put Left/Right